# How to use multiple database in Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen, lumen-5.2, lumen-5.3

We've using Lumen for building API's , Now we need to access multiple databases.

Currently using `.env` for database config but unable to found the way to multiple databases in `.env`

where we need to read 2nd connection ...

Comment: we Need both databases

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use multiple database in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-laravel)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, you'll need to configure your connections. If you don't already have one you'll need to create a `config` directory in your project and add the file `config/database.php`. It might look like this:

```
<?php

return [

   'default' => 'accounts',

   'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST'),
            'port'      => env('DB_PORT'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
         ],

        'mysql2' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB2_HOST'),
            'port'      => env('DB_PORT'),
            'database'  => env('DB2_DATABASE'),
            'username'  => env('DB2_USERNAME'),
            'password'  => env('DB2_PASSWORD'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Once you've added your `connection` configurations, you can access them by getting the database manager object out of the container and calling `->connection('connection_name')`.

```
// Use default connection
app('db')->connection()->select('xx');
DB::connection()->select('yy');

// Use mysql2 connection
app('db')->connection('mysql2')->select('xx');
DB::connection('mysql2')->select('yy');
```

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: this file is under `/vendor/laravel/luman-framework/` directory. Is it ok to modify such a file? It seems it should be a way to put this in a place where the repository could notify the rest of the devs group that they need to define new env variables. Any ideas?

Comment: @GaboLato: Hi, thanks for question! It's not good to make changes in `vendor` folder. Please find that file and if you want to see more info visit this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215265/lumen-create-database-connection-at-runtime

Comment: Because if you make changes in `vendor` folder, it'll only change in your local server not in your prod server and you need to make changes also in your prod server's `vendor` folder which is not a good practice!

Comment: I found out that if you create a directory `/config` and a file `database.php` in your project's root directory lumen will overwrite the vendor's file. Thanks!

Comment: one other thing that needs to be added in  bootstrap/app.php is    $app->configure('database');

Answer (score 5):

This also worked. In the current version of Lumen 5.7

config/database.php

```
<?php

return [

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),
    'migrations' => 'migrations',
    'connections' => [
        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],

        'sqlsrv2' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE2', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],
    ],
];
```

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=database1
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password

DB_DATABASE2=database2
```

Usage:

Model: `protected $connection = 'sqlsrv2';`
Other: `->connection('sqlsrv2')`

I hope i help you!

Reference:https://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections

Comment: thank you, got exactly what I am looking for. multiple database connections with eloquent